# How to avg() in linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm trying write my sql commang to Linq:

**SQL:**

```
select avg(sub.evaluation) from submit_task sub where student_id='" + idStudent + "' and state='close';
```

**Linq:**

```
double avg = (ado.submit_task.Where(r => (r.id == idStudent && r.state == "close")).Average(r => r.evaluation));

avgStudent = avg.ToString();
```

but this is not working, when I delete `&& r.state == "close"` statement, I got result, but it's incorrect.

thank you.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "not working"? You said you got a result in some situation but was incorrect, what result did you get, what did you expect?

Comment: Also note that in your SQL version you should use a parameterized query anyway...

Comment: by "not working" I mean, that  find no record in db, but when I delete this statement I got result, f.e.:from values: 5, 10, 15 I got avg=4

Comment: Is it possible the state is "Closed" and not "Close"? :)

Comment: Close is name in db, any idea what's wrong ??

Comment: What does ado.submit_task.Where(r => (r.id == idStudent && r.state == "close")) return? and ado.submit_task.Where(r => r.id == idStudent)?

Comment: Is is possible that `r.id` in your linq query is referring to a different field than `student_id` in the sql query?  All the other relevant names are the same between the two, so I'm wondering if the two queries are filtering on different fields.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried the same with a sample set of data and it works fine

```
 List<student> students = new List<student>
        {
            new student{id="1",state="close",evaluation=5},
            new student{id="1",state="close",evaluation=4}
        };
        double avg = (students.Where(r => (r.id == "1" && r.state == "close")).Average(r => r.evaluation));

public class student
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public int evaluation { get; set; }
}
```

may be you should check the data in the db or modify the `state="close"` part of the query

Comment: @user1726810: Please check the count of the number of objects in `ado.submit_task` and if possible post the database table data [sample] and also the model to check the datatype of state property.

Answer (score 0):

ok, here's code, which working:

```
var avgEvalClose = (from sub in ado.submit_task
                    where sub.student_id.Equals(idStudent)
                    where sub.state.Equals("close")
                    select sub.evaluation).Average();
avgStudent = avgEvalClose.ToString();
```